# asp.net Network error 403 forbidden

Tags: asp.net, ajax, iis

Firebug listing this error on every page load. error is something like below 
 "NetworkError: 403 Forbidden - http://abc.xyz.com/ScriptResource.axd?d=DPF5-8SyZial685PXcRQnwbpO5cuuY6q1d84oGVYrpU-NCjcc0gxIYbp5-ka3mv60&t=d02bdad"

32 error listed on single page.

its a normal asp.net application written in c# with javascript and Ajax and hosted on Windows Server Standard with application pool .Net framework version set to v2.0

With Windows Authentication for LDAP authorized users only

Comment: we don't have SSL certificate for this application....

Comment: If you try to use the address for one of your image files (png, jpg) do you get this error, or is it only for code?

Comment: No where it mention png,jpg files in the error , it simply refer to some SCriptResource.axd and webResource.axd @tgolisch

Comment: I tried all possible solutions available online like changing IIS Managed Pipelines in app pool, webconfig etc

Comment: do you find solution for this problem